# Does the octopus have an anus? What does it look like?

Tags: zoology, anatomy, cephalopods

Octopuses are cephalopods, which have separate anal and oral openings. Indeed, [descriptions of the cephalopod GI tract](http://tolweb.org/accessory/Cephalopod_Digestive_System?acc_id=1993) clearly depict an anal opening.

However, I am very confused about how this applies to the octopus. I don't think I've ever seen the anus depicted - where is it? What does it look like? Does anything much come out?

My first instinct would be to simply do a google image search for this. Unfortunately, those results are flooded with unrelated hits (apparently the octopus is a popular motif for tattoos... in a *certain* part of the body).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The anus of Octopus is channeled into its siphon.
[image]
Image taken from [Carina M. Gsottbauer](https://twitter.com/carinadslr/status/683001936803659777)

Note:

> Siphon is a tube that leads from the mantle to the outside. Octopuses use their siphon to force water out in jets for propulsion and to flush waste products from the anus.

<sub>From [**Encyclopedia of the Aquatic World, Volume 6
By Marshall Cavendish Corporation**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=swGA8GtK4n8C&pg=PA768&dq=octopus%20anus%20siphon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxst-g8cjOAhXGs48KHZfRAqkQ6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=octopus%20anus%20siphon&f=false)</sub>

Comment: And here I was thinking that the siphon just ejects clean, harmless water... I'll keep this in mind next time I encounter an octopus!

Comment: I would imagine that you'd probably have to worry more about that poison gland than the highly-diluted waste that is ejected from the siphon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't the poison of Octopus injected through a bite? http://www.thecephalopodpage.org/octobite.php

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh please add citations to your answer on where the image and quote originated. If you use images and/or text that are not your own words, you need to cite the sources.